# Getting the following error message in wine when I try to run Exact Audio Copy

Tags: wine

I just recently figured out how to install wine1.5. My primary purpose is to use Exact Audio Copy without having to reboot back to Windows.

I re-downloaded the installation executable, ran it, and installed it into my external hard drive. When I then tried to get wine to run it, it will give me the initial "Exact Audio Copy is starting up... Please Wait!" but then a second window opens. The second says the following message:

"Unhandled exception -

[X icon] at 0207ADF0 -> ACCESS VIOLATION"

Cancelling the window or hitting "ok" cancels wine entirely.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why don't you just use one of the native Linux audio extractors, like sound-juicer?

Comment: EAC is generally regarded as the best ripping program due to the quality of the rips. Is sound-juicer as good?

Comment: If you have a decent drive, then it doesn't matter what program you use, you will always get a correct rip.  For older/buggy drives, sound-juicer uses the original bad rip correcting program: `cdparanoia`.

Answer (score 3):

I did the following to get it working:

```
cd ~/.wine/dosdevices/c\:/Program\ Files\ \(x86\)/Exact\ Audio\ Copy/
```

or wherever you installed EAC to.

```
regsvr32 sql*
```

Goto EAC options (F9) and Change the interface to "Installed external ASPI interface".